# Índice compartido?, Como separar Array con índice compartido

Tags: python

Buenas tengo el siguiente problema.
No se como o porque se comparte el índice al mostrar este array, quiero decir que al seleccionar por ejemplo el índice 2 instantáneamente me muestra el índice 2 de todos los arrays dentro de este. Mi pregunta es como puedo separar los arrays para tratarlos de forma individual.

class Sismos():

```
def ObtenerSismos():
    if(respuesta.status_code==200):
        print("Acceso Permitido")
        datosSismos=json.loads(respuesta.text.encode("utf-8"))
        for recorrer in datosSismos['ultimos_sismos_chile']:
         regi=("\tFecha : {} | Magnitud : {} | ID : {}".format(recorrer['chilean_time'],recorrer['magnitude'],recorrer['id']))
         num=([(s) for s in re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', regi)])
         print(num[2])
    else:
        ("Error al registrar")
```

Sismos.ObtenerSismos()

en consola muestra algo así
19
19
19
17
16
15
12
10
10
10
10
09
09
08
08
06

```
    Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:58:09 | Magnitud : 4.7 | ID : 54626750
    Fecha : 2022/12/19 23:08:53 | Magnitud : 4.5 | ID : 33074081
    Fecha : 2022/12/19 17:10:49 | Magnitud : 4.9 | ID : 29755599
    Fecha : 2022/12/17 13:18:06 | Magnitud : 4.1 | ID : 14920741
    Fecha : 2022/12/16 23:07:29 | Magnitud : 4.3 | ID : 53134779
    Fecha : 2022/12/15 02:38:25 | Magnitud : 4.2 | ID : 98929057
    Fecha : 2022/12/12 05:35:53 | Magnitud : 4 | ID : 54006485  
    Fecha : 2022/12/10 22:32:08 | Magnitud : 4.1 | ID : 42142890
    Fecha : 2022/12/10 05:49:02 | Magnitud : 4.6 | ID : 99623628
    Fecha : 2022/12/10 04:25:49 | Magnitud : 5.4 | ID : 16334919
    Fecha : 2022/12/10 03:41:29 | Magnitud : 5.6 | ID : 41177912
    Fecha : 2022/12/09 19:00:14 | Magnitud : 4.4 | ID : 79854050
    Fecha : 2022/12/09 05:06:26 | Magnitud : 4.8 | ID : 79885673
    Fecha : 2022/12/08 17:55:40 | Magnitud : 4.4 | ID : 49802790
    Fecha : 2022/12/08 08:21:36 | Magnitud : 4.4 | ID : 11802796
    Fecha : 2022/12/06 13:48:19 | Magnitud : 4.3 | ID : 68370888
```

Comment: ¿Puedes subir un ejemplo  o captura de cuando te lo enseña con todo array?

Comment: ['2022', '12', '19', '23', '58', '09', '4.7', '54626750']
['2022', '12', '19', '23', '08', '53', '4.5', '33074081']
['2022', '12', '19', '17', '10', '49', '4.9', '29755599']
['2022', '12', '17', '13', '18', '06', '4.1', '14920741']
['2022', '12', '16', '23', '07', '29', '4.3', '53134779']
['2022', '12', '15', '02', '38', '25', '4.2', '98929057']
['2022', '12', '12', '05', '35', '53', '4', '54006485']  
['2022', '12', '10', '22', '32', '08', '4.1', '42142890']
['2022', '12', '10', '05', '49', '02', '4.6', '99623628']
Es un poco mas largo pero no me deja por los limites del comentario

Comment: Como puede ver los arrays van juntos por asi decirlo aunque estan en sus corchetes no estan con comas y no se como separarlos (son arrays dentro de otro array)

Comment: Eso que muestras en el comentario es lo que contiene la variable `datosSismos`? Puedes mostrar lo que sale si haces un `print(repr(datosSismos))`? (si no te cabe en un comentario puedes editar la pregunta para ampliar información)

Comment: es una variable aparte que ocupe solo para sacar los valores numericos de la original "datosSismos" ya que la necesito para operar condicionales. Enseguida le mando el print de la original como dice

Comment: Lo puse en la pregunta pero aun asi apenas cabe

Comment: Mm.. sí, ya veo que hay ahí demasiada información irrelevante. ¿Puedes editarla de nuevo y cambiar eso por lo que sale al hacer `print(repr(datosSismos['ultimos_sismos_chile']))` ?

Comment: Sale mas de lo mismo pero sale distinto pero cuando imprimo la variable regi que es el resultado de usar un bucle for en la api me da lo siguiente:

Comment: No se quien respondio recien a la publicacion dando la solucion a mi problema ni se porque se borro pero muchas gracias por ayudarme con el problema, de momento soy nuevo en la plataforma y no se como ser reciproco con la ayuda

Comment: Fui yo entendí que me había equivocado (erróneamente por lo que parece) por eso la borre ya la he recuperado si te sirve la marcas como válida para cuando otros lleguen sepan que esta funciona. Saludos

Comment: Ya la marque, muchas gracias que tengas buen día!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El indice no se comparte lo que haces es iterar cada uno de los subarrays que se forman el for por lo que el indice de l'array cogida durante la iteracion.
Primero es declarar una variable array antes del for:

```
aux=[]
```

lo que printabas en vez de printarlo añades a la array con un append (el str es para si no es string de entrada en mi prueba no lo era):

```
  aux.append(str(num[2]))#el str solo es porque lo probe con int
```

Finalmente, metes el print fuera del for y usas el join con el separador de coma:

```
print(",".join(aux))
```

El codigo de demo pequeña que hice para comprovar el funcionamiento:

```
val =[ [1,2,3,1,2,4,5,6,3,2,1],[1,2,3,1,2,4,5,6,3,2,1]]
aux=[]
for v in val:
    aux.append(str(v[2]))

 
print(",".join(aux))
```

El resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adaptando tu codigo al la solución con índice quedaría así:

```
def ObtenerSismos():
    if(respuesta.status_code==200):
        print("Acceso Permitido")
        datosSismos=json.loads(respuesta.text.encode("utf-8"))
        aux=[]
        for recorrer in datosSismos['ultimos_sismos_chile']:
         regi=("\tFecha : {} | Magnitud : {} | ID : {}".format(recorrer['chilean_time'],recorrer['magnitude'],recorrer['id']))
         num=([(s) for s in re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', regi)])
         aux.append(num[2])
        print(",".join(aux))
    else:
        ("Error al registrar")
```

En caso de querer solo en comas todos los datos de l'array puedes obviar el aux
def ObtenerSismos():
if(respuesta.status_code==200):
print("Acceso Permitido")
datosSismos=json.loads(respuesta.text.encode("utf-8"))

```
        for recorrer in datosSismos['ultimos_sismos_chile']:
         regi=("\tFecha : {} | Magnitud : {} | ID : {}".format(recorrer['chilean_time'],recorrer['magnitude'],recorrer['id']))
         num=([(s) for s in re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', regi)])
        
         print(",".join(num))#dentro del for
    else:
        ("Error al registrar")
```